# How to configure email in Sonarqube?

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, email

We were trying to configure secure mail connection in sonarqube . 
Mail connection works fine when secure connection is NOT enabled .

But there are issues when we enable secure connection .
We tried using Secure connection as 'ssl' and 'starttls' with ports '465' and '587' respectively. But that didn't work.
Can anyone guide me on this one ?
What should be entered in SMTP username field?

[image]